# Bluetooth does not work any longer

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

Bluetooth has worked on my Lenovo W530 equipped with Xubuntu 20.04. When it worked last, lsusb showed the adapter as

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
```

but now it is missing in the output of lsusb.

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
[sudo] Passwort für verwalter:
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Nov 15 16:26:49 W530-SSD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
$
```

Looking at `/var/log/syslog` I found

```
Nov 15 16:26:49 W530-SSD dbus-daemon[1104]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.39' (uid=110 pid=1406 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
Nov 15 16:26:49 W530-SSD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Nov 15 16:26:49 W530-SSD pulseaudio[1406]: module-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.
```

Since there is something about pulseaudio in the line above the error message and there is another error message related to it below, they all might be in some relationship.

**Where exactly can I find more information on which condition check failed such that Bluetooth was skipped and does not work any longer?**

**How can I remove the obsolete module-rescue-stream from my configuration?**

Answer (score 0):

After googeling for this problem I came across [similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608116/bluetooth-wont-turn-on-on-ubuntu-20-04)

The most accepted answer there was

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth  # rfkill also needs root privileges
```

In my case the second statement first did not work on 2 consecutive trials, just telling "Abgebrochen" (stopped) after I had verified that I wanted to install the upgrade. I verified that free space is not an issue, only 14,3 kB had to be upgraded: `libssl-dev`, `libssl1.1`, `openssl`, `python3-software-properties`, `software-properties-common`, `software-properties-gtk`.

When I finally had succeeded with the upgrade, the other two commands went through without producing any output. Bluetooth did not work and `lsusb` did not show the Bluetooth-adapter.

After one more reboot, `lsusb` showed the Broadcom adapter:

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]`

The Bluetooth symbol was also present on the task bar again. I was able to transmit some pictures from a mobile phone to my computer.

My main problem is solved, but I do not understand why this fix worked.

However, in `/var/log/syslog` still appears is a line after the last boot process:

`Nov 15 20:57:21 W530-SSD pulseaudio[1830]: module-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.`

that proves that this message had nothing to do with the BT problem.

So I still ask for two explanations:

1. **Why did applying the recipe from the other website work in my case? What has gone probably wrong before?**
2. **What do I have to do to fix the cause of the other error message about module-rescue-stream?**

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Even after a reboot, `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` told me `Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)`. Further `rfkill list` told me about Bluetooth being Soft blocked and Hard blocked!

Comment: Today I found out that as a side effect of renaming `.cashe`,  `lsusb` found the Broadcom bluetooth device again. I could also use my bluetooth headphone again after that. - Strange! What might have been an explication for this non-functioning before?